# Evaluate $\int\frac{e^z-1}{z}\mathrm dz$ along the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

How do I evaluate the following integral?
$$\oint_{C}\frac{e^z-1}{z}\mathrm dz$$ where $C$ is the unit circle (counter-clockwise).

I have just learned Cauchy-Goursat's Theorem, but I cannot apply it here since there is a singularity at $z=0$. So I try to go brute force and evaluate the contour integral as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{e^{e^{it}}-1}{e^{it}}ie^{it}\,\mathrm dt = \int_{0}^{1}({e^{e^{it}}-1})i\,\mathrm dt .$$
But then I'm stuck again as to how to evaluate this.

Thanks!

Comment: It is a removable singularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no singularity at $0$: let $g(z)=1+\frac z {2!}+\frac {z^{2}} {3!}+...$. Then Goursat theorem can be aplied to $g$. But $f$ and $g$ are one and the same functions on the unit circle so the integral is $0$.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about it this way at all, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since$$\frac{e^z-1}z=\frac{z+\frac1{2!}z^2+\frac1{3!}z^3+\cdots}z=1+\frac1{2!}z+\frac1{3!}z^2+\cdots,$$the integral is $0$.